# What does the "squid:" Prefix mean in SonarLint Rules?

Tags: rule, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I just started using the SonarLint plugin for Eclipse to analyze my Java code.  I was wondering, what does the "squid:" prefix mean in SonarLint Rule keys?  Does it stand for something? (see screenshot below)

[Sonar Rules Config Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfK6g.jpg)

Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, it is SonarQube Unique ID -> squid. However, my colleagues could correct me if I'm wrong :)